# how can you create rotating testimonials within a joomla module (joomla 1.5)

Tags: joomla, text-rotation

I have a new client that has an older 1.5 Joomla site. I don't have much experience with Joomla but I have been able to update it so far. There is a testimonial in a module in the right sidebar. If I add several testimonials they will just continue down the right side. This will create a very long homepage instead of rotating. I know it rotated before but the code was deleted...:(

I know it something very simple but I just have that much experience with Joomla and no one here can help..

Here is what I have

```
<p>11/26/13</p>
<p><i>“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam non quam vitae sapien egestas posuere. Nam laoreet lacus in diam bibendum cursus. Phasellus nec commodo enim, vitae aliquam lacus. Nunc ultrices odio vel rutrum elementum. Duis sit amet massa ut nunc suscipit adipiscing at quis ipsum. Donec porta aliquam enim, sed congue nisi placerat et. Curabitur vel porta sem, sed ultrices tellus. Fusce malesuada pulvinar purus a facilisis. Ohio to Texas</i></p><br><a href="about/reviews" mce_href="about/reviews">Read More...</a><br mce_bogus="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install this module:

http://www.dynatec.at/joomla-extensions-modules-plugins-components/content-slider-module-for-joomla-1-5

I have an example here on this site:

http://five-elements-sd.com/center

I did some custom styling to it.

Comment: Thank I am checking it out. The thing is that I am almost 100% sure that in order to get multiple testimonials to rotate there was just some special tag that I am not aware of. I am hoping that someone know about them instead of doing a whole new extension...

Comment: There are no native "tags" you can add in Joomla 1.5 that will make it rotate. There is a newsflash module that will randomly load a testimonial on each page refresh though. If your old code was deleted, then your only recourse would be to install new code. To install a module in the administrator go to Extensions->Install/Uninstall, then upload the new module. Should take about 5 minutes. Then go to manage modules and create a new one, choosing the "content slider module". It only has a few settings and off you go.

Comment: @user2101421 - You're not by any chance referring to the `<marquee>` tag are you? If so then do bare in mind that this is an obsolete feature

Comment: obsolete even for 1.5? Huh. I didn't know it was a tag never used it before but MDN says not to use bc maybe be different for every user...